# Need to add 40 amp doublePole

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Currently needing to install double pole breaker to supply power to AC unit. Not much space on panel but was wondering if there was anything that could be moved around or combined together to provide space for the breaker.[image]

Comment: It will depend on that panel.  Some panels allow the use of tandems/half size breakers.  If not you might need to add a sub panel to have more breaker places.

Comment: That's a BRyant or Cutler Hammer "BR" panel.  It takes Eaton BR breakers. (Cutler Hammer has been a brand of Eaton since 1968; they just now started branding things Eaton but it's the same kit). The two yellow-button breakers (2-pole?) are **AFCI** for bedrooms, which would put this work around 2008 +/- a few years, when states adopted NEC 2005 requiring AFCI breakers in bedrooms, but before AFCIs started looking all fancy with the LEDs and stuff lol.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the labeling on the inside of the panel's dor please?

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues with adding a new circuit:

- Total Load == Load Calculation

In this particular case, unlike many, you are probably OK. Assuming this is your main panel, you have 200A service. (If it is actually a subpanel, you might only have 100A service, in which case a load calculation is definitely a good idea.)

- Breaker Spaces

You may be in luck here. I am not in favor of half-size (tandem) breakers. However, if your panel permits them then that is a good solution here. *We need to see a picture of the panel labeling, typically inside the panel door, to know for sure.* Some panels (generally older) don't permit half-size breakers at all. Some permit them only in certain locations. But assuming they are allowed, the easy thing to do is to replace 4 15A breakers with a quad 15A (or 2 x tandem 15A) or 4 20A breakers with a quad 20A (or 2 x tandem 20A). That would free up a pair of full size spaces for the new HVAC.

There are some limits to tandem/quad breakers. GFCI/AFCI is one problem, but you only have 2 of those right now (the breakers with the yellow test buttons). Another problem is Multi-Wire Branch Circuits, but most likely you don't have any of those as they would (should...) be handle-tied. To check for MWBCs, when you remove the cover to change breakers, look for any red wires. If you have black from one cable going to one single breaker and red from the same cable to another single breaker then you have an MWBC and things get a little trickier to do correctly.